# Update multiple entities in one PUT request (or POST)

Tags: c#, ajax, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a website that allows clients to enter tabular information (merchants) into a grid. Each record can be identified by a unique id. I am trying to enable bulk updates through my Web API controller, instead of individual PUT requests. These requests are made through AJAX on the page (no post back/submit). Individual updates are working fine.

This is the code for individual updates:

```
// PUT api/Merchants/5
public HttpResponseMessage PutMerchant(int id, Merchant merchant)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ModelState);
    }

    if (id != merchant.MerchantId)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    db.Entry(merchant).State = EntityState.Modified;

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
    {
        return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
    }

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

What I would like to build is a similar PUT for bulk updates (something like this):

```
// PUT api/Merchants
public HttpResponseMessage PutMerchants(Merchant[] merchants)
{
    ...
}
```

Is this possible and does it follow RESTful conventions? Also, since some merchants should be updated and others created, do I use POST to split them up? How are these situations generally handled with Web API controllers?

Comment: Usually, PUT is for updates and POST is for new records. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically,  HttpPost is for new records and HttpPut is for updating. Here is a really good stackoverflow answer on the differences between the two.

[PUT vs POST in REST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

That being said, you can pass in a list in either case:

```
   // PUT api/Merchants
    public HttpResponseMessage PutMerchants([FromBody]List<Merchant> merchants)
    {

    }
```

Comment: How does this affect the routing? The current PUT uses `api/merchants/id` from AJAX. Won't multiple PUTs conflict with each other?

Comment: I would use Attribute based routing to avoid conflicts.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: I opted for the routing by convention as per your example. Thanks!

Comment: update one object but multiple fields (properties names- properties values) ?